# Can we calculate magnitude of instantaneous velocity by directly differentiating the magnitude of position vector of a particle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, coordinate-systems

Let there be a particle in a plane at any general time instant $t$. Let the coordinates of the particle are $x\mathbf{\hat i} + y\mathbf{\hat j}$, where $x$ and $y$ are functions of time $t$. Then we calculate velocity as $v_x=dx/dt$ and $v_y=dy/dt$. Then we write velocity as

$$\mathbf v= (dx/dt)\mathbf{\hat i} + (dy/dt)\mathbf{\hat j}$$

And its magnitude is given as $\sqrt{(dx/dt)^2 +(dy/dt)^2}$.

But can we do like this to directly find magnitude of velocity:

Magnitude of $r$ vector=$\sqrt{(x^2 + y^2)}$ then magnitude of velocity$=d/dt$ of $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$. I checked it with examples and found the answer to be no. But I am not able to figure out why.

Answer (score 3):

The position vector of any particle in [polar coordinates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) is

$$\mathbf r =r \mathbf {\hat r}$$

where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\mathbf{\hat r}$ is the unit vector in the radial direction. Thus differetiating the position vector with respect to time gives us

$$\frac{\mathrm d \mathbf r}{\mathrm d t}=\left(\frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d t}\right)\mathbf {\hat r}+r\left(\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf{\hat r}}{\mathrm dt}\right)$$

The above equation is just the application of [product rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) of differentiation.

Simplifying the above equation, we get

$$\frac{\mathrm d \mathbf r}{\mathrm d t}=\left(\frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm d t}\right)\mathbf {\hat r}+r\omega\, \boldsymbol{\hat {\theta}}$$

where $\omega =\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d \theta}{\mathrm dt}$ and $\boldsymbol{\hat {\theta}}$ is the unit vector in the tangential direction. If we use the *dot notation*, then we get

$$\dot{\mathbf r}=\dot r \mathbf{\hat r} + r\dot{\theta}\, \boldsymbol{\hat {\theta}}$$

Thus the magnitude of velocity is

$$|\dot{\mathbf r}|=\sqrt{\left(\dot r\right)^2 + \left(r\dot{\theta}\right)^2}$$

Your expression only includer the term $\dot r \mathbf{\hat r}$ which pertains to the radial velocity. This expression fails to account for the transverse motion which is represented by the term $r\dot{\theta}\, \boldsymbol{\hat {\theta}}$. Thus you are bound to get a wrong answer if you only consider the radial velocity.

Remember that $|\mathbf v|=\displaystyle \left|\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf r}{\mathrm d t}\right|$, but $|\mathbf v|\neq\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d|\mathbf r|}{\mathrm d t}$.

Comment: But what about my question. Can you give a clear explanation why we cannot find the magnitude of instantaneous velocity by differentiating the magnitude of displacement.

Comment: @ayushsharma Because you can have motion with fixed magnitude but changing direction just like this answer mentioned mathematically. Take for example a particle moving in a circle with constant speed. Here magnitude of displacement is a constant and differentiating that will give you zero! But we know that it’s moving! That’s because the change is entirely in the direction. Or $\hat{\theta}$ in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

In a planar motion, let us define the position of the particle by a vector $\vec{r}$ or $\mathbf{r}$ as made up of two components i.e. the ordered pair {x,y} in the unit basis vector $\{\hat{\mathbf{i}}, \,\,\hat{\mathbf{j}}\}$ as

$$\mathbf{r}= x \,\,\hat{\mathbf{i}}+ y \,\,\hat{\mathbf{j}}$$

Now the **norm** or length (i.e. the size or magnitude) of the above vector is

$$ ||r||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Suppose, we have the coordinates of the body given by

\begin{eqnarray}
x(t)= 2 t^2 \\
y(t)= 3 t
\end{eqnarray}

then the velocity coordinates would be given by $\frac{d \mathbf{r}(t)}{dt}$ as
\begin{eqnarray}
v_x= 4 t \\
v_y= 3
\end{eqnarray}

Let us take the norm of the $\mathbf{r}(t)$ i.e.

$$  ||r||= \sqrt{4 t^4+ 9 t^2}$$
If we take the derivative with respect to time we get $\frac{8 t^3+9 t}{\sqrt{4 t^4+ 9 t^2}}=\frac{8 t^3+9 t}{||r||}$; and if we compare it to the  $||v||$ i.e. $\sqrt{16 t^2+9}$.

The difference is because they are actually two **different vectors** having **different components**, to begin with! Their dependence on the parameter *t* is not the same. Thus, we find that

$$\left|\left|\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt}\right|\right| \neq \frac{d ||\mathbf{r}||}{dt}$$

Since, the L.H.S defines the derivative of a vector quantity, while, the R.H.S is a derivative of a scalar quantity.

The first quantity is the magnitude of $\underline{\textit{tangent vector}}$ ; while the second one is sort of a $\textit{`gradient'}$ (in the sense of a *slope*) of a scalar.

**NB:** The vector $\mathbf{r}$ is written as $||r||\, \hat{\mathbf{r}}$. However,the Cartesian coordinates have a special property that the basis is independent of space and time and hence their derivatives vanish when using the product rule.

Comment: One doubt - you mentioned that "they are actually two different vectors". But isn't $\frac{d||\mathbf{r}||}{dt}$ just a scalar? I'm a bit confused on how it's a "gradient of a scalar", given that $||\mathbf{r}||$ is nothing but a function of the parameter $t$ and we're taking its derivative w.r.t. that parameter. Finally, be "magnitude of tangent vector", do you mean the magnitude of the tangential velocity? Just wanted to clarify for my own sake.

Comment: The two different vectors are **r** and **v**. We start our discussion with these vectors. The vector **r** is long the curve in a plane while **v** is tangent to that curve at the same point. The point of application is same for them but components are different. We parametrize the **r** with a parameter t, one could take any parameter , say arc length, and do the same steps. Remember, that the gradient of a scalar functions is a vector. If the magnitude of **r** is $\sqrt{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}$ then take the gradient of this function. Chain rule applies.

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry if I sounded stupid but I thought the gradient of $||\mathbf{r}||$ would be $\nabla||\mathbf{r}||=(\frac{\partial ||\mathbf{r}||}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial ||\mathbf{r}||}{\partial y})=(\frac{x}{||\mathbf{r}||},\frac{y}{||\mathbf{r}||})=\frac{\mathbf{r}}{||\mathbf{r}||}$, so that got me confused. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: you can *upvote* the main answer if you like. :)

Comment: It's a good answer for sure but I _still_ don't understand how the time derivative $\frac{d||\mathbf{r}||}{dt}$ can be called the gradient of anything, because it certainly doesn't seem like the gradient of $||\mathbf{r}||$. $\nabla ||\mathbf{r}||$ is a vector while $\frac{d||\mathbf{r}||}{dt}$ is a scalar. I'm almost sure I've misunderstood your point. Did you mean 'gradient' in the sense explained here: https://amsi.org.au/teacher_modules/Introduction_to_coordinate_geometry.html#The_gradient_of_a_line ?

Comment: you are right. The 'gradient' is an ambiguous term here since it does not have *unit vectors* associated with it. The **Slope** is a better choice of word. So, one should say that the slope of the scalar function.

Comment: Aha now I understand! I also see you've edited it to make it clearer. Upvoted!

Comment: :) Thank you for a good discussion.